# in rails 3.0 I want to use a partial view in a show and in an edit, for edit I want to show the link to delete

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

<%= question.name %>
    
      Created <%= time_ago_in_words(question.created_at) %> ago.

<% if  :action == "edit" then %>
  
    <%= link_to "delete", question, :method => :delete,
                                     :confirm => "You sure?",
                                     :title => question.name %>
  
  <% end %>

Comment: Please use the code block formatting (highlight your text and press the "{ }" icon).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `action_name` like so:

```
<% if action_name == 'edit' %>
  <%= link_to 'delete', question, :method => :delete, :confirm => 'You sure?', :title => question.name %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: If that answered your question, please click the checkmark to mark it as the accepted answer. Thanks (and you're welcome, too)